# Magento 1.9.2 - enlarged product image "restores back" to original size (210px) after click on swatch (RWD theme)

Tags: image, magento, product

Successfully resized (enlarged) product image on product list (grid) in:

```
app/design/frontend/rwd/my-theme/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
```

...and looks like this:

```
src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')
                     ->init($_product, 'small_image')
                     ->constrainOnly(TRUE)
                     ->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)
                     ->keepFrame(FALSE)
                     ->resize(230, 345); ?>"
```

and they display OK - with 3 products per row, also configured in XML file:

```
app/design/frontend/rwd/my-theme/layout/catalog.xml
```

Everything is OK but everytime I use swatch image (color) to dynamically change product image (ajax?), they are restored back to 210px dimensions. Further check confirmed that they are loaded (actually asynchronically replaced with Ajax) with "cached" product images from this directory:

```
media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/210x
```

Firebug shows:

*Original image before clicking the swatch square:*

```
    <img id="product-collection-image-22" 
    class="hidden" 
    alt="Product 100" 
    src="http:<my-domain>/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/230x345/
         89b1df1394338e37a97daa6040ec056f/p/e/product_100_black_1.jpg">
```

*Replaced (restored to original 210px) product image:*

```
    <img class="product-collection-image-22" 
    src="http:<my-domain>/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/210x/
         a5e241f90fa2c1f01d1b56f4e8602ff9/p/e/product_100_black_1.jpg">
```

Any help how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

According to me you don't have to change the src of image for changing the size.

If you see default theme of magento in rwd package

Open `app/design/frontend/rwd/my-theme/template/catalog/product/list.phtml` go to line number 128 and you will find `<?php $_imgSize = 210; ?>` if you change this variable then your all images will change including swatch one.

Also try to refresh Catalog Image Cache Go to System >> Cache Management.

Comment: Obviosly the line with `$_imgSize` was changed in `list.phtml` at first place. The thing with Swatches is they change Product Image automatically and asynchronously, with Ajax - and it is Ajax that chooses the "source" of the replaced image (not me). I tried to find out the function (js, ajax?) that chooses that directory (from which "replacement image" is displayed on swatch click).

Comment: In RWD theme there is no AJAX used to change the images of product on swatch click. You can also check this on console, open your list page and click on swatch then you will see they are not sending any AJAX request to get the image.

Comment: Again - I do not change the `src` of image (if it is no Ajax, then jQuery, sorry). It is then jQuery that chooses the source folder (onclick Swatch image) to replace Product Image (e.g.300px) with standard (`210px` from Cache folder). I try to find this `jQuery/JavaScript` function...

Answer (score 0):

a little late but i found the answer. The 210px is the default size of the **Magento** small_image. And this size is set in Back-end.

Go to System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Product Image

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, I tried editing $_imgSize in list.phtml and also System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Product Image size changed.
It doesn't generate the smaller image. It is using full size.

I have a feeling it has something to do with product-media.js or swatches-list.js